# How does the Client in a docker image know the ip address of a server which is in another docker image?

Tags: django, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am using React Client, Django for the backend and Postgres for the db. I am preparing docker images of the client, server and the db.
My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    build: ./client
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on: 
     - server

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
     - db

  db:
    image: "postgres:12-alpine"
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - "5432:5432"
    environment: 
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: bLah6laH614h
```

Because the docker images can be deployed anywhere separately, I am unsure how to access the server from the client code and that of the db's ip in the server. I am new to react,django and dockers. Please help!

Comment: Is your question about how to connect those services inside `docker-compose` or elsewhere?

Comment: if I have to make a post request to server from client, what ip address should I use?

Comment: I've posted an answer, did it helped? Did I miss something? Please let me know ;D

Comment: Thanks Bernardo. I am still working on server. will update on it in a day.

Comment: Checking back again ;D If you need any help just ask!

Comment: @Bernardo, Priorities changed and my sprint calls for more work on front end and backend comes in later sprints. So, I will have to wait before testing integration with backend. I will update how it works out when i get there. Thanks for following up. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using your `docker-compose.yml` file configuration as basis 4 things will happen, as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

1. A network called `myapp_default` is created. *(Let's say that your project folder is name `myapp`)*
2. A container is created using db’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `db`.
3. A container is created using server’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `server`.
4. A container is created using client’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `client`.

Now to send an `HTTP` request from `client` to `server` you should use this URL:

```
http://server:8000
```

because of item `3` and because the `server` configured port is `8000`.